# Creacion de una clase en Django que tenga una clave a si misma

Tags: python, django, django-models

Estoy adentrándome en el mundo de `Django` y estaba probando a generar diferentes tipos de modelos. Ahora estoy creándome un modelo con una clase 'Tags' la cual tenga una clave que llame a otro objeto de la clase (Para crear objetos enlazados por relación). El caso es que estuve leyendo y no encuentro la respuesta que me funcione. Os dejo aquí la clase que hice:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tagname= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    related_tag = models.ForeignKey ('self',null=True)
```

He probado también con related_name en los argumentos y con related_query_name, pero no estoy muy seguro si los usé bien. Los puse así:

```
related_tag = models.ForeignKey ('self',null=True,related_name='Tags',related_query_name='Tags')
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, finalmente y después de varios intentos, lo he conseguido, asi que me respondo yo solo y os pongo la solución por si alguien la necesitara en un futuro.

Para que Django sepa que la ForeignKey puede estar vacía y así funcionar dentro del panel de Administración, hay que poner:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
   tagname= models.CharField(max_length=20)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   related_tag = models.ForeignKey('self',default=0,null=True,blank=True)
```

Aunque quizás el campo default no es necesario.

Pero despues he tenido que borrar las migraciones de la aplicación que estoy creando, ya que creo que Django se hace un lio con ellas:

```
(<dentro de tu aplicacion>/migrations)$> rm *
```

Después solo hay que volver a sincronizar las migraciones y todo funciona correctamente.

De todas maneras si alguien tiene una solución mejor explicada, que me lo diga, para saberlo ;)

Gracias!